# libssh2 lib with ipv6 not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, ssh, ipv6, libssh2

In my iOS application I am using libssh2 library. I am trying to ssh with ipv6 address, But socket is not creating and getting nil socket. It's working fine with ipv4 address.

```
static CFSocketRef _CreateSocketConnectedToHost(NSString* name, UInt16 port, CFOptionFlags callBackTypes, CFSocketCallBack callback, const CFSocketContext* context, CFTimeInterval timeOut)
```

I have search for this but not finding any result for ipv6 support with libssh2.

Please help me, Is libssh2 not supporting for ipv6? Can we make it working using libssh2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just need to use ipv6 property in socket instead of ipv4 and you able to create socket with ipv6 address.

```
struct sockaddr_in6 ipAddress6;
CFSocketSignature           signature;

ipAddress6.sin6_port = htons(port);
signature.protocolFamily = AF_INET6;
signature.protocol = IPPROTO_IP;//IPPROTO_IPV6;
signature.address = (CFDataRef)[NSData dataWithBytes:&ipAddress6 length:ipAddress6.sin6_len];
```